# MVC Identity pass E-mail from login to register/forgotpassword page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

Using the provided identity framework in MVC I find it annoying that when a user try to logs in, does not succeed (because the user does not exist or the password is wrong), decides to go for 'register as a new user' or 'forgot password', the user needs to retype his/her e-mail - address.

So I made some minor changes.

Step 1 :
In the login View. Add html-attribute id to the register/forgotpassword link :

```
@Html.ActionLink("Register as a new user", "Register", null, new {@id = "RegisterLink" }) | 
@Html.ActionLink("Forgot your password?", "ForgotPassword", null, new { @id = "ForgotPasswordLink" })
```

Step 2 : add JQuery script to the login view.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $BaseRegisterLink = $('#RegisterLink').attr('href');
    var $BaseForgotPasswordLink = $('#ForgotPasswordLink').attr('href');
    var $InitialEmail = $('#Email').val();
    if ($InitialEmail != "")
    {
        $('#RegisterLink').attr('href', $BaseRegisterLink + "?Email=" + $InitialEmail);
        $('#ForgotPasswordLink').attr('href', $BaseForgotPasswordLink + "?Email=" + $InitialEmail);
    }
    $('#Email').on('input', function () {
        $('#RegisterLink').attr('href', $BaseRegisterLink + "?Email=" + $(this).val());
        $('#ForgotPasswordLink').attr('href', $BaseForgotPasswordLink + "?Email=" + $(this).val());
    });
});
```

Step 3 : added a parameter to the AccountController.Register/Forgotpassword GetMethod.

```
public ActionResult Register(String Email)
{
    if (Email != null) return View(new AppUserCreateVM() {Email = Email } );
    return View();
}

public ActionResult ForgotPassword(String Email)
{
    if (Email != null) return View(new ForgotPasswordViewModel() { Email = Email });
    return View();
}
```

Because the StackOverflow community brought me so much value so far. I wanted to share this. If you have any suggestions on this, I'am open to learn to do it in better ways.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not a questions. Unfortunately StackOverflow is site about questions and answers. Questions like this will be closed as don't fit the format.

Comment: I hope the don't delete it, I wanted to give something back to the communicaty. Anyhow I put it also in a blog-post. https://brilbroeder.wordpress.com/wp-admin/post.php?post=61&action=edit&message=6&postpost=v2